# FTP connectivity issue from Mule

Tags: ftp, mule, mule4

I am receiving the below error while connecting the FTP path for file transfer through
Mulesoft code and it is worked for so many days, unfortunately, we received this error from a
couple of dys. So please help me to fix this.

Error

```
Message: An exception was found trying to obtain a connection: Found exception trying to change transfer mode to class org.mule.extension.ftp.api.ftp.FtpTransferMode. FTP reply code is: 421
Element               : ac-ngwtransform-ftp-v1Flow/processors/6/processors/0/route/0/processors/1 @ azx-us-int-ac-ngwtransform-ftp-v1:ac-ngwtransform-ftp-v1.xml:84 (Reading the file from FTP)
Element XML           : <ftp:read doc:name="Reading the file from FTP" doc:id="da9be7af-d84b-4a78-a8ce-cd9f117aa273" config-ref="FTP_Config_NGW" path="#[attributes.fileName]" outputMimeType="text/plain"></ftp:read>
Error type            : FTP:CONNECTIVITY
Payload Type          : org.mule.runtime.core.internal.streaming.bytes.ManagedCursorStreamProvider
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPConnectionClosedException: FTP response 421 received.
```

Comment: Can you download the file using any GUI/commandline FTP client?

Comment: In addition to what @MartinPrikryl asked, what version of the connector is used? Please share the connectors configuration as text XML.

Answer (score 1):

you can use reconnection strategy to fix this issue.
go to your ftp connector-->advance->click reconnection and make the reconnection strategy standard.